# Checking if robots.txt file exists in python3

Tags: python-3.x, robots.txt

I want to check a URL for the existence of `robots.txt` file. I found out about `urllib.robotparser` in python 3 and tried getting the response. But I can't find a way to return the status code (or just true/false existance) of `robotss.txt`

```python
from urllib import parse
from urllib import robotparser

def get_url_status_code():
    URL_BASE = 'https://google.com/'
    parser = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    parser.set_url(parse.urljoin(URL_BASE, 'robots.txt'))
    parser.read()
    # I want to return the status code

print(get_url_status_code())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too hard to do if you're okay using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module **which is highly recommended**

```
import requests

def status_code(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.status_code

print(status_code('https://github.com/robots.txt'))
print(status_code('https://doesnotexist.com/robots.txt'))
```

Otherwise, if you want to avoid using a GET request, you could use a HEAD.

```
def does_url_exist(url):
    return requests.head(url).status_code < 400
```

Better yet,

```
def does_url_exist(url):
    try: 
        r = requests.head(url)
        if r.status_code < 400:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        # handle your exception
```